# Twilio how to make text to speech call

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio, twilio-api

I want to make a call which will convert provided text into speech to deliver it user on call.

I have referred [say](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/say) API, but I am not getting how to make a request so that the voice call will be delivered to the recipient.

I am using [twilio-node](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-node) library for my case.

I have

```
account_sid,
auth_token,
recipient's phone number
and text
```

How to achieve this.

Answer (score -1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Can I recommend you take a look through our [quickstart guide for voice calls with Node.js](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/node/programmable-voice). It shows you how to make calls and how to generate [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml) so that you can use the [`<Say>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/say) command to turn text to speech.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have gone through documents. In my case, I have text that needs to convert it into TwiML and use say command.  Can you show some code which will do this, because I am getting any combine code which makes perfect understanding?

Comment: As I have only text value so I am looking for API which will take my code convert it into speech which will use in voice call just to read that text.

Comment: Ok, if you go through the tutorial you will see that you can add your text into a `<Say>` block in the return TwiML. That will turn it into speech on the phone call. Can you try the tutorial and let me know how it goes?

Comment: But how can I use this TwiML to make phone call

Comment: Sam, have you gone through the tutorial?

Comment: I have gone through it. But is it necessary to upload voice XML somewhere, can I send XML file stream with the call?

Comment: You do need to host an application somewhere that will respond with TwiML using the `<Say>` element to speak your text. If you don't want to host anything yourself, you can check out [TwiML Bins for static TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/05/introducing-native-twiml-bins-powered-by-the-twilio-cloud.html) or [Twilio Functions](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/runtime/functions) for running Node.js.